# Problems for laravel project on share hosting server where I cannot run npm run dev or build

Tags: laravel, npm, web-hosting, laravel-jetstream, npm-build

I used jetstream laravel authentication and I used `npm run dev` and keep it running on my cmd while I developed my project locally. Everything was OK till here. But now I want to upload on a shared hosting. And I got it that I need to run `npm run build` now. I have run it locally and uploaded the files but my ui of my project has been all scattered and misplaced. So I know I have missed a/some steps. What really have I missed out or have wrongly done.I am stuck now.
Regarding my web hosting ,I have my project files outside the public_html. All the public files are moved in this folder public_html.My database and my application working fine except the ui is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out a way but still do not know whether it is the best solution or proper one.
What actually the scenario is that the build folder of the `npm run dev` is folder `project_folder/public/build` but I have my project files outside the `public_html` folder. So it was unable to find the `manifest.json` in the folder `project_folder/public/build`. It was not working ,the UI is very ugly.   Then, I put only the manifest.json in `project_folder/public/build` but the `app.####.cs` and `app.###.js` is kept in the `public_html/build/assets`. And now it is working fine. Hope this help someone like me, even though it might not be the right approach.